# Access Violation with no apparent nullptr

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, mfc, access-violation

I am writing an MFC application and have created a derived class `CStatusBarPane` which publicly derives from `CMFCRibbonStatusPane`. This derived class contains a simple method as follows:

```
virtual void SetStatusIcon( _In_ HICON hIcon )
{
     m_hIconSmall = hIcon;
     Redraw();
}
```

After the Main Frame is created (along with the status bar and its children panes), I call the following function:

```
void CMainFrame::UpdateStatusBar( _In_ const std::tstring& szStatus, _In_opt_ HICON hIcon )
{
     CStatusBarPane* pStatusBarPane = static_cast<CStatusBarPane*>(m_wndStatusBar.GetElement(0));

     pStatusBarPane->SetText( szStatus.c_str() );
     pStatusBarPane->SetStatusIcon( hIcon );
}
```

However, when I debug the application, it raises an exception on the line `pStatusBarPane->SetStatusIcon( hIcon )` with the following statement:

> First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

However, looking at the variable trace shows that there are no null pointers being accessed, so I don't understand how I can have an access violation at address 0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this access violation is not the more common type where you attempt to read or write a memory address. In this case the error is that you are attempting to execute code at address `0x00000000`. So that would indicate that you are calling a function whose address is the null pointer.

The most obvious explanation would seem to be that `m_wndStatusBar.GetElement(0)` is in fact not a `CStatusBarPane*`. If that is the case, and since `SetStatusIcon` is a virtual function, your code will be trying to perform vtable lookup on `m_wndStatusBar.GetElement(0)`. And obviously that can only work if `m_wndStatusBar.GetElement(0)` really is what you think it is.

Comment: I can't believe I just did that; I checked that several times and it was only as I was typing the generating line of code here that I finally realised I'd created the base class instead of the derived class; I'm such a fool, thank you!